# How do I INSERT into Big Query via Apps script with a 2D array from a Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have a blank table in big query with the schema set up.

I have data in a Google sheet with the columns in the same order as the table Schema.

When I get the data from the Google spreadsheet I'm given a 2D array [[xxx1,yyy1,zzz1],[xxx2,yyy2,zzz2]] etc

How do I INSERT the array content into the Big Query table?

I think I need to use the following code - but what is the format of the **data** variable and how would I get my array to that format

```
let job = {
configuration: {
  load: {
    destinationTable: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId
    }
  }
}
};
job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data [what do I need here??]);
```

Many thanks

EDIT: I should add I can't just connect the google sheet directly to the table and stream.  The sheet is simply a stop gap to gather weekly rows of data and add a few bits to it then dump it to Big query - will end up with many 100's of thousands of rows so can't stay in Google sheets

EDIT2: Also the data is various types of Strings, Integers and Dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem:

- `BigQuery.Jobs` accepts blob `data`. So you need it in blob form.

#### Fix:

- Use `newBlob` to convert data into blob form.

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getRange("A1:B2").getValues();
  // rows data is 2D string array
  Logger.log(rows); 

  // newBlob only accepts String so we convert rows into one
  var rowsString = rows.join("\n");
  Logger.log(rowsString);

  // data below is now of type Blob object
  var data = Utilities.newBlob(rowsString, 'application/octet-stream');
  Logger.log(data); 
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### References:

- [Appending new Google Sheets Data into BigQuery Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869807/appending-new-google-sheets-data-into-bigquery-table)
- [Apps Script, convert a Sheet range to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002917/apps-script-convert-a-sheet-range-to-blob)
- [newBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata)