# Append a new record in BigQuery with Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I need to add (append) records to a Big Query table from Google Script. I have looked for similar questions and came up with this code (Also I activated the Advanced Service for BigQuery API):

```
 const data = {"Name":"TEST","Key":"TEST"};

var projectId = 'myid'
var datasetId = 'mydatasetid'
var tableId = 'mytableid'

var job = {
    configuration: {
      load: {
        writeDisposition:'WRITE_APPEND',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }       
      }
    }
  };

   var runJob = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data);
```

I get an error: "The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload."

I know I could use this method to add data from a CSV file, but I would like to add an array instead. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem:

- `BigQuery.Jobs` accepts blob `data`. So you need it in blob form.

#### Fix:

- Use `newBlob` to convert data into blob form.

```
function test() {
  // data is currently an object
  var data = {"Name":"TEST","Key":"TEST"};

  // newBlob only accepts string, so convert data to string
  data = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(data), 'application/octet-stream');
  // data below is now of type Blob object
  Logger.log(data); 
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

- You can now use data on `BigQuery.Jobs` as it is now Blob type

#### References:

- [Appending new Google Sheets Data into BigQuery Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869807/appending-new-google-sheets-data-into-bigquery-table)
- [Apps Script, convert a Sheet range to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002917/apps-script-convert-a-sheet-range-to-blob)
- [newBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata)

Comment: Nice, I actually tried this before, but I was getting an error. Now I realize I was getting an error because I was using CONST and not VAR to define the array. Thanks!